# I just Need to create centralized DNS/LDAP for 3 cloud provider AWS, GCP, Alibaba

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-chrome, cloud, alibaba-cloud

I Need to create a centralized DNS server or LDAP for All the cloud platform ..AWS, GCP, Alibaba.

Need a tools name and what is the approach to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run DNS and LDAP servers in real VMs you can use any DNS server and any LDAP server product provided the products support replicating the data over TCP and you set up network connection between all the different public cloud deployments.